# jQuery-Events: How To Unbind Keyup Event If One Input Detected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've currently this function here:

```js
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));

input[0].add(input[1] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    console.log("Keyup!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1"/>
<input id="test2"/>
```

It works but I've a bit of a problem. I need to unbind the keyup event if one of the two inputs are detected so that the other one don't works anymore. How can I do this?

As result, only one log `Keyup!` should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

u can unbind with jquery-off -method (https://api.jquery.com/off/) like so:

```js
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));

input[0].add(input[1] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    $(input).each(function() {
      $(this).off("keyup");
    });
    console.log("Keyup!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1"/>
<input id="test2"/>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

So, this was my solution:

```js
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));


input[0].add(input[1]).one("keyup", function() {
 console.log('keyup!');
  
  for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
   if(input[i].attr('id') != event.target.id){
     input[i].unbind();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" />
<input id="test2" />
```

Don't know if you'll like it, but I find useful to know which element triggered the event in order to use this info after. 
Moreover, you'll be able to add more elements to `input` array and automatically unbind the event from them too.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve that you can add an extra data attribute and check against that:

```
<input id="test1" data-disabled="false"/>
<input id="test2" data-disabled="false"/>
```

Then your js would look like this:

```
input[0].add(input[1] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("data-disabled")==="true") {
      return false;
    }
    $(this).siblings().attr("data-disabled","true");
    console.log("Keyup!");
});
```

Comment: Not an option because the input is still neded. Only the keyup function should be disabled / remove!!!!!!!!!